# How to manage state smarter in this case so that frequent copy operation isn't costly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js, state

I'm writing a real time graph component for my React app and as my app is receiving data from the WS server, it's getting more and more laggy as time goes on because of the way I use my set function like so

```
socket.on('data', (data) => {
      setDataPoints((prevData) => {
        return [...prevData, ...data]
      })
    })
```

Since it's receiving data every X ms and afaik the spread operator just means copying the prevState and it's getting more and more laggy because the array is becoming too big. Now I could obviously have a limit as such

```
if (data.length > Y){
    // Do some slicing here
}
```

But then again I want to hold data of several minutes so that the user can look back and zoom into each data points if necessary, so how do I go about managing my state for this component in a smart way?

Comment: Are you sure the slow comes from the spread operator? Have you measured the perf of the `setDataPoints(...)` code? (ex: `console.time("label")`). I suspect the slow might come from drawing the graph itself. I guess every time new data comes in, the graph has to erase and then redraw everything. Obviously, bigger data requires more time to draw. On the second thought, maybe you can try a different graph library to compare perf.